# Pass additional parameters to load event JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How do I pass additional parameters to a load event? Here is an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
var imageID = 'this-is-my-img-id';
var image;

reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e, imageID, image){

    image = '<img src="'+e.target.result+' id="'+imageID+'" >';

}

reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Comment: You cannot. However due to how scoping works in Javascript, the `image` vbariable defined in line `2` is available inside the anyonymous function defined for `onload`, and you can just read it, without passig it as an argument

Comment: What is the purpose of `image` variable?